# Wordpress pagination not working in search results

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I have this search.php with the results of my search by year/genre:

```
<?php get_header();
$loop             = new TOROFLIX_Movies();
$sidebar_position = $loop->sidebar_position('sidebar_type_category'); ?>
<div class="Body">
    <div class="Main Container">
        <?php get_template_part('public/partials/template/letters'); ?>
       <div class="TpRwCont <?php echo $sidebar_position; ?>">
            <main>
                <section>
                    <div class="Top AAIco-movie_filter">
                        <h2 class="Title">
                            <?php if(isset($_GET['genre']) or isset($_GET['years'])){
                                echo 'Afisez ce doreste sufletul tau! :)';
                            } else {
                                echo get_search_query();
                            } ?>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="MovieList Rows AX A04 B03 C20 D03 E20 Alt">
                        <?php if(isset($_GET['genre']) or isset($_GET['years'])){ ?>
                            <?php $args = array(
                                'post_type'           => array('movies', 'series'),
                                'posts_per_page'      => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
                                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                                'no_found_rows'       => true,
                                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                            ); 
                            if( isset( $_GET['genre'] ) && $_GET['genre'] != '' ){
                                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'    => $_GET['genre']
                                );
                            }
                            if( isset( $_GET['years'] ) && $_GET['years'] != '' ){
                                $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'annee',
                                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'    => $_GET['years']
                                );
                            }
                            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                                    get_template_part("public/partials/template/loop-principal");
                                endwhile;
                            endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        <?php } else{
                            if(have_posts()) : 
                                while(have_posts()) : the_post();
                                    get_template_part("public/partials/template/loop-principal");
                                endwhile; ?> 
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <div>
                                    <?php _e('There are no articles', 'toroflix'); ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif;
                        } ?>
                    </ul>
                           
                </section>                
            </main>
            <?php if($sidebar_position != 'NoSdbr'){ get_sidebar(); } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The settings for

```
'posts_per_page'      => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
```

in wordpress are to display 200 results. I want those results to be paged, let's say 20 posts per page then next, next.. Inside the page, no other links for results page.

I tried to add

```
<nav class="wp-pagenavi">
<?php echo TOROFLIX_Add_Theme_Support::toroflix_pagination(); ?>
</nav>
```

, a code that I got from the Category page, where paginations works without problem, but does not display anything related to pagination in search results.
The Category page code is:

```
<?php get_header();
$loop             = new TOROFLIX_Movies();
$sidebar_position = $loop->sidebar_position('sidebar_type_category'); ?>
<div class="Body">
    <div class="Main Container">
        <?php $alphabet = get_option('alphabet_show');
        if($alphabet){
                get_template_part('public/partials/template/letters');
            } ?>
        <div class="TpRwCont <?php echo $sidebar_position; ?>">
            <main>
                <section>
                    <div class="Top AAIco-movie_filter">
                        <h2 class="Title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="MovieList Rows AX A04 B03 C20 D03 E20 Alt">
                        <?php if(have_posts()) : 
                            while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
                                <?php get_template_part("public/partials/template/loop-principal"); ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?> 
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div>
                                <?php _e('There are no articles', 'toroflix'); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <nav class="wp-pagenavi">
                        <?php echo TOROFLIX_Add_Theme_Support::toroflix_pagination(); ?>
                    </nav>
                </section>                
            </main>
            <?php if($sidebar_position != 'NoSdbr'){ get_sidebar(); } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and the category's navigation works just fine, how can I get the same results on the search page results?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familliar with the Trolofix functions, but have you tried using the default WP

```
the_posts_pagination()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/
or

```
paginate_links()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

Also try to figure out what `OROFLIX_Add_Theme_Support::toroflix_pagination()` does?

This might give you a clue on how to add your own pagination on the search.php file